# Rails app Active Record Reputation System Error Caller Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, railscasts, rating-system

I have just finished implementing ARRS, following R. Bates Railscasts #364.
I changed it to fit my app, so

> a user votes on a movie in show view

Which is quite different to r. bates' one where

> a user votes on a haiku in index view

And upon launching, the buttons look fine and they appear on the show view.

yet when i click on one this error appears

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Any ideas anyone?

Movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController



  # GET /movies
  # GET /movies.json
  def index
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
    @movies = Movie.all


  end

  # GET /movies/1
  # GET /movies/1.json
  def show

      @movies = Movie.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: 'votes desc')
      @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])


  end




    def search
        @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
        @movies = @search.result

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @movies }
        end
    end

  # GET /movies/new
  # GET /movies/new.json
  def new
      @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
    @movie = Movie.new


  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
      @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
def create
    @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @movie, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # PUT /movies/1
  # PUT /movies/1.json
 def update
     @search = Movie.search(params[:q])
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update_attributes(params[:movie])
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # DELETE /movies/1
  # DELETE /movies/1.json
  def destroy

    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
  end



def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @movie.add_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting!"
end

end
```

Movie.rb

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

User.rb

```
has_reputation :votes, source: {reputation: :votes, of: :movies}, aggregated_by: :sum
```

show.html.erb //movies

```
<div class="ratings">

  <em>
    <%= pluralize @movie.reputation_for(:votes).to_i, "vote" %>
    | <%= link_to "up", vote_movie_path(@movie, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
    | <%= link_to "down", vote_movie_path(@movie, type: "down"), method: "post" %>
  </em>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :movies do
    member { post :vote }
  end
```

Comment: can you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Okk did that? Anymore code or is everything there?

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb`? what line is the error on in the trace?

Comment: add the whole stacktrace

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mpcoding/7c881eae3c01c5579e15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @movie.add_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting!"
end
```

the problem might be here:

```
add_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
```

requires `current_user`that you don't have. Devise documentations says you need to include
`before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the conotroller to use the `current_user` helper.

Pay more attention to documentations when using a gem.

**EIDT** after chatting to solve this issue the `acts_as_votable` gem was used
https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable instead of `Active Record Reputation System`

Comment: I now get this error ----         undefined method `add_evaluation' for #<Movie:0x007fac88e70f40>         ----     When clicking up or down

Comment: And i am logged in as current_user, and there is a before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:vote]

Comment: You  must be finding movie by wrong param, may movie is passed as  movie_id and not just id, so you need to use @movie =Movie.find(params[movie_id])

Comment: or,double check how you implement the voting system. Your question has been answered

Comment: what is the link for upvote? And one more thing, there is a common rule in SO to mark an apropriate answer as accepted if it solves your problem, I helped you in a previous problem of yours and in this one, are you sure none of my answers helped you?

Comment: Sorry about that since we had continued it in chat i forgot to mark it correct, but your answer did help me tremendously!!

<div class="ratings">
  
  <em>
     <%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_movie_path(@movie, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
    | <%= link_to "Vote Down", vote_movie_path(@movie, type: "down"), method: "post" %>
  </em>
  (<%= @movie.reputation_for(:votes).to_i %>)
</div>

Comment: In your app as I remember you are using slugs instead of ids, so putting `@movie` in a link would send a parms id as a slug and not an integer, you might want to try to force sending an id by using @movie.id in your links.

Comment: <%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_movie_path(@movie·id, type: "up"), method: "post" %>  and in controller at voting action find movie by params[:id]

Comment: `<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_movie_path(@movie.id, type: "up"), method: "post" %>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31800/discussion-between-user2225129-and-rmagnum2002)

Answer (score 0):

here the problem is in your add_evaluation line

change it to 
'add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)'
this will add and also update the evaluation part.